# Elastic search group by with filter not working

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I have joined couple of tables while indexing while trying to get the group by it is not working.

Initially I have executed this one

```
{
    "size": 10000,
    "query": {
        "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "test_id"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Afterwards I have modified the search query to add the aggregations as I am looking for group by it is giving same number records, even though there are multiple records showing with the same id.

```
{
    "size": 10000,
    "query": {
        "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "test_id"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "group_test_id": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "test_id"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am unable to figure out where i did wrong, trying from past couple of hours, any help would be great.

Comment: What response do you get and what do you expect to get instead?

Comment: I am getting all the records which test_id is not null. But I looking for grouping the test_id.

Comment: And what doesn't work? Your query looks correct

Comment: @Val group by seems to have no effect results is same as initial

Comment: @Val I have not done any mapping for that column at first time, later i have tried to add the mapping column is integer. Still no use

Comment: @Val original column name in the MySQL table is different I have used as syntax while join, will it make any difference?

Comment: I'd like to see some response data to get a feeling of what you're experiencing.

Comment: I just test with my simular data in a ES 1.X cluster, work without problem. As Val asked,  give us some exemple + mappings. And yes name field (case sensitive) are really important and could explain your issue (EDIT: didnot see the date, this topic gone up because of the following answer :))

Answer (score 1):

You should give the size value 0 when using aggs

```
{
        "size": 0
        "aggs": {
                "groups": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "test_id",

                    }
                }
            }
}
```